# Java - Big O of .get and .remove for Arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I assume ArrayList.get and ArrayList.remove both have a big O of O(n) correct?

**Therefore, my code below will have a time complexity of O(n^2), right?**

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestingJava {

    public ArrayList<Integer> plusOne(ArrayList<Integer> a) {
        // If vector has [1, 2, 3]
        // returned vector should be [1, 2, 4]
        // 123 + 1 = 124
        int total = 0;

        // O(n)
        for(Integer i: a){
            total = 10*total + i;
        }

        total += 1;
        int last_dig = total%10;
        a.set((a.size()-1), last_dig);

        // O(n**2)
        while (a.get(0) == 0){
            a.remove(0);
        }

        return a;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> a1 = new ArrayList<>();
        a1.add(0);
        a1.add(1);
        a1.add(2);
        a1.add(3);
        TestingJava c = new TestingJava();
        System.out.println(c.plusOne(a1));
        // Should output [1, 2, 4]. Should NOT output [0, 1, 2, 4]
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I am simply practicing for interviews, this is not homework or an assignment. If you want to practice this problem you can go [interviewbit.com](http://interviewbit.com)

Comment: Why would `get()` be O(n)? `ArrayList` is backed by an array.

Comment: @LoganKulinski isn't get() searching the ArrayList and therefore would rely on the length of the ArrayList? I'm new to java, so I'm tryinng to figure out the time complexity of the methods.

Comment: @Theo `get()` does not search the `ArrayList`. All it does is go to the element at a specific index, like an array using square brackets.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch This question is not about the 2 loops, it is about simply the second loop. If .get is O(n) and .remove is O(n) then this code would be O(n^2)

Comment: `get` runs in constant time (aka O(1)). The JavaDocs are explicit about that. They're not explicit about `remove`, but it is indeed O(N).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Ahh okay, and would remove() be like del() in python?

Comment: @yshavit Perfect thanks! This would mean that my code runs in O(n).

Comment: That said, this _is_ O(n^2). The reason isn't because of `get(0)` per se; rather, it's that the `while` loop might run N times (if all of the elements in the list are == 0), and for each one of them, you perform an O(N) remove.

Comment: @yshavit ahh yes, you're right, I was too fixated on the get(), that I forgot about the while loop itself being O(n).

Comment: `remove` is `O(n)` because you have to move all elements to the right of the deleted element one position to the left. `get` is `O(1)` like others have said because `ArrayList` is backed by an array which has a constant time access time complexity

Answer (score 0):

First, I would always prefer to program to the `List` interface; instead of `ArrayList` directly, *doubly so* in a public method signature. Instead of iterating the values from the left, you could start at the right. This is `O(n)` but contains nested loops. Carry until the current value isn't `9`, once it is just copy from the right until you hit `0` **and** then `return`. Like,

```
public static List<Integer> plusOne(List<Integer> a) {
    List<Integer> b = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = a.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int val = a.get(i);
        if (val == 9) {
            b.add(0, 0);
            continue;
        }
        b.add(0, val + 1);
        while (i > 0 && (val = a.get(--i)) != 0) {
            b.add(0, val);
        }
        return b;
    }
    b.add(0, 1);
    return b;
}
```